# Gitlab CI - Job wouldn't run on main branch

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have the following job in my ci file. When I push commits in the main branch, it does not get triggered.

```
build:source:prod:
  environment: prod
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo HelloWorld
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main"
      changes:
        - src/*
```

For some reason, even if I change a file within the src directory it still wouldn't run. But when I changed the rule to the following, the pipeline was triggered including the build job. Am I missing something here?

```
build:source:prod:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "test-branch"
      changes:
        - src/*
```

Comment: does it work wthout the `changes`.